# Removing Objects in one-to-many relationships using Node.js REST API, Mongoose, Express, Angular,

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, rest, one-to-many

I have a one to many relationship between Tickets(many) and Events(one). I am able to add a Ticket to an Event but when I delete that Ticket I want it to be removed from the Event as well. So far I have not been able to accomplish this with the code below. I am able to delete the ticket but it's still referenced in the Event object.

ticket controller (Delete function) **OLD**

```
    exports.delete = function (req, res) {
  // Find Ticket using ID from URL
  var ticket = Ticket.findById(req.params.ticketId, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: "Could not retrieve event with id " + req.params.ticketId
      });
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  });

  //Use ticket linkedEvent Id to find and update Event
  Event.update( {"_id": ticket.linkedEvent}, { "$pullAll": {"tickets": [req.params.ticketId] } } );

  //Delete Ticket and send back success message
  Ticket.remove({
    _id: req.params.ticketId
  }, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: "Could not delete ticket with id " + req.params.id
      });
    } else {
      res.send({
        message: "Ticket deleted successfully!"
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Ticket Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TicketSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  type: String,
  name: String,
  expirationDate: String,
  reward: String,
  image: String,

  rewardUnlocked: Boolean,
  redeemed: Boolean,
  linkedEvent: String,
  scannedCodes: [],
  unlockCodes: []
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Ticket', TicketSchema);
```

Event Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var EventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  promoter: String,
  name: String,
  location: String,
  date: String,
  image: String,

  attendees: Array,
  tickets: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'Ticket'
  }],
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema);
```

Async Waterfall Delete Function **NEW**

```
exports.delete = function (req, res, next) {

async.waterfall([
getTicket,
updateEvent,
deleteTicket,
], function (err, result) {
res.send(result);
});
//Get Ticket by Id
function getTicket(req, res, callback) {
Ticket.findById(req.params.ticketId, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: "Could not retrieve event with id " + req.params.ticketId
    });
  } else {
    callback(null, data);
  }
});
}
//Delete Ticket ref from Event
function updateEvent(callback) {
Event.update({
  "_id": callback.linkedEvent
}, {
  "$pullAll": {
    "tickets": [req.params.ticketId]
  }
});
next();
}
//Delete Ticket
function deleteTicket(callback) {
Ticket.remove({
  _id: req.params.ticketId
}, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: "Could not delete ticket with id " + req.params.id
    });
  } else {
    callback(null, {
      message: "Ticket deleted successfully and removed from Event!"
    });
  }
});
}
};`
```

Comment: Check the result of the Event.update (which should be updateOne), and you should probably wait on that before continuing anyway or you could leave your data in a broken state. Check the values result.ok and result.nModified.

Comment: I think its ok to leave the ticket id inside the event for a while and just garbage collect it somewhen

Comment: It looks right in broad strokes. Does req.params.ticketId need to be converted to an ObjectId in the $pullAll

Comment: I updated my code with an async waterfall but whenever i run the app and try to delete a ticket it skips completely over the waterfall. Why is that?

Comment: Did you check out my answer?

Comment: @HRK44 Yes and i have been working on a solution but havent gotten it working quite yet. I posted my new async waterfall code in an edit above.

Comment: The code i have now is a bit different than what i posted there. I've been trying to keep this up to date as often as i can work on this. https://github.com/kellykels21/JourneysRESTAPI

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same issue like you, so the only you need is to update the parent document when you delete the child:

```
// remove child document and pick its id and parent_id
await Event.findByIdAndUpdate(event_id, {
    $pull: { tikets: tiket_id },
});
```

by the way you need in the child schema a reference to the parent, something like this:

```
  var TicketSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    // ...other properties
    event: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'Event'
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: true
  });
```